# JAVA retrieve all printers from all windows user accounts

Tags: java, windows, api, user-accounts, printers

Is there any way to retrieve all the printers installed by various windows user accounts on same machine.

lookupPrintServices() method of the javax.print.PrintServiceLookup class displays all the printers which can be seen in the Control Panel in Windows for logged in user.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: user selects a printer from server and sends a document to that printer for printing. Server has two user accounts(user A and user B). Now user A can see only his printers and B can see only his printers. Is there any way in java which retrieves printers installed by both users A and B

Comment: @SadurdinaGAP You're now suddenly talking about printers on a *server*, but your question is about registered/configured printers on your *local* machine.

Comment: This sounds more like a Windows setup problem.

Answer (score -1):

It will help

```
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;


public class CheckInstalledPrinter {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        System.out.println("Total Services :: " + printServices.length);

        for (PrintService printer : printServices)
            System.out.println("Printer Name :: " + printer.getName()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: As per my execution of above code it returns printer names from control panel not from other windows user account who has installed different printers.